# Properly create a file with tab when doing loop

Tags: bash

I have this command line:

```
while read line
do 
echo $line >> Ho
grep -c "0/1/0" file_$line\.hwe >> Ho
done < my_file
```

Which will give me something like that:

```
ID1
689
ID2
747
etc.
```

I was wondering how I can make the loop so that the ls and grep command print on the same line instead of different lines.  Here is what I want to obtain:

```
ID1  689
ID2  747
etc.
```

Any clue?
Thanks!

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, just:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
   echo "$line"$'\t'"$(grep -c "0/1/0" "file_$line.hwe")"
done < my_file >> Ho
```

or maybe:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
   printf "%s\t%s\n" "$line" "$(grep -c "0/1/0" "file_$line.hwe")"
done < my_file >> Ho
```

But still you could:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
   echo "$line" 
   grep -c "0/1/0" "file_$line.hwe"
done < my_file |
paste -d $'\t' - - >> Ho
```

Comment: `printf` is definitely preferred, as its simpler, standard, and doesn't rely on any shell settings that can alter the behavior of `echo`.

Comment: Another option: let `grep` provided the newline. `while ...; do printf '%s\t' "$line"; grep -c "0/1/0" "file_$line.hwe"; done < my_file; >> Ho`. This gets rid of the unnecessary command substitution.